# Java ArrayList attributes changes

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist object catalogHierarchy of type CatalogHierarchy.

The catalogHieriarchy object has three elements. Each element has two attributes like headerName and hierarchyList. The hierarchyList element contains multiple elements of type ProductHierarchy.

I have to set a value of an attribute to Y based on headerName.

The problem I am facing is, I am making the change only for element whose headerName contains text Hierarchy. But after the iteration the catalogHierarchyFlag is set for all other two elements of cloneList object.

Could anyone please help me how to overcome this issue.

```
ArrayList<CatalogHierarchy> catalogHieriarchy = ... //values from database
List<CatalogHierarchy> cloneList = (ArrayList)catalogHieriarchy.clone();
for(int a=0;a<cloneList.size();a++){
    if(cloneList.get(a).getHeaderName().contains("Hierarchy")){
        List<ProductHierarchy> catalogHier = cloneList.get(a).getHierarchy();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < catalogHier.size() ; i++) {
            catalogHier.get(i).setCatalogHierarchyFlag("y");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<CatalogHierarchy> catalogHieriarchy = "Vale from DB";` This sentence makes no sense.

Comment: `Object#clone` provides a shallow copy of the object being cloned. You should avoid using this approach.

Comment: how about using getHeaderName().equalsIgnoreCase("Hierarchy")?

Comment: Maroun Maroun - Instead of writing entire method call for fetching from DB, I gave in double quotes

Comment: ha9u63ar - The problem is not with that conditional check. I am okay with contains..

Comment: Do you also create the hierarchies that are returned by `getHierarchy()` for each item by either reusing objects or doing a shallow clone rather than a deep copy? I suspect your items all share the same hierarchy object, but you need to show us that code.

Comment: David - I might have to perform Deep copy but I couldn't make the startup on that..

Answer (score 0):

Read about deep vs. shallow copies. It looks like if you compare your Objects with the `==` operator, it will return `true`, indicating that the Objects share the same reference. If you want to create an independent copy of the Object (one that does not share the same reference but that has the same values for the fields) you will have to reimplement the clone() method or provide another method. See the java docs.